# Dividing a column by 12, MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

trying divide by 12 in MySQL query,I am trying to show `Firstname`, `Surname` column and divide there total `Salary` (another column) buy 12.
this is what I have so far.

```
SELECT `Firstname`,`Surname`
FROM 'employee'
WHERE `Salary`/12;
```

can some one correct me where I am going wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to fetch firstname ,surname and the respective salary which is divided by 12.

```
SELECT `Firstname`,`Surname`,Salary/12 as Salary
FROM employee
```

** Remove single quotes from "`FROM 'employee'`",as it will through error in mysql and most of

```
                             -----^
```

the sql.